# open word using vba

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I keep getting error runtime 424 when opening a word document from excel. I double-checked the file path as well. The file path seems correct.

```
Sub OpenDoc()
    Dim strFile As String

    strFile = "C:\Users\risha\Downloads\english_2850_paper.docx"    'change to path of your file
    If Dir(strFile) <> "" Then    'First we check if document exists at all at given location
        Documents.Open strFile
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you doing this inside of Word? Or in some other application (like Excel, looking at your tags)? 424 means it does not know what `Documents` is.

Comment: I am using VBA code in excel to open a word document.

Comment: Then take a look at my 2nd comment.